# What's the best practice for integrating C components into a C++ framework?

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns

What's the best practice for putting a C component into a C++ framework?

Our lab is building a C++ framework for our research. It uses some existing software as components. My job is to integrate software in C. The structure of the software is quite simple:

- A set of `extern` variables in A.h
- A set of data structures definitions and function prototypes in B.h.
- The rest of the source code are .c files implementing the functions defined in B.h.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth considering whether the style of client usage can usefully be improved using the additional features of C++.  You can often trivially wrap C functions for a more C++-style experience.  For example:

- objects may be able to:

  - cleanly encapsulate data returned by some function calls that is then used as inputs to later calls, making its storage and usage more implicit
  - provide some guarantees about the correct sequencing of construction (initialisation), usage and destruction (clean-up)
- namespaces can help group and disambiguate the identifiers
- operator overloading can allow operations on types to be notated more like mathematical or logical expression, (e.g. `x = a + b` instead of `x = add(a, b)`)
- exceptions might reduce the number of places in the client code where error values have to be explicitly checked for and handled (useful if this error-related code is currently obfuscating the program logic)
- if any of the functions implement generic functionality via void*s, then templates could be provided as a front end, automating the conversion to and from the `void*` type

This just off-the-top-of-my-head stuff... it's much easier to give concrete answers if you show a representative sample of the functions.

And of course, as you say you have the C source code, you can try compiling it with the C++ compiler, which would give you the option of avoiding "extern C" and a bit of the pollution of the global namespace, as well as adding much of the above not as wrappers but as tweaks to the existing code: may save you time and make maintainence easier.

Comment: +1: `cleanly encapsulate data returned by some function calls that is then used as inputs...` this is especially true for all those C APIs which from a C++ perspective are actually modelled "inside out", like using a opaque HANDLE or whatever context, that could be flipped into a class.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping all the C header and source files with:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//... rest of the file

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This is compile and link properly in a c++ compiler. This is just an initial step. Depending on the implementation and how the functions are used in the C code, the c++ compiler may complain about few things. But try this as a your first step.

See [here](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html#c_from_cpp) for a nice introduction on how to access C functions from C++.